# VBA - pass variable between Excel projects

Tags: vba, excel, global-variables, add-in

**My question:** How can I set value of a variable declared in other Excel Project?

Background:
I am working on calling a private sub from a diffrent Excel Project (I don't know if it matters, but the sub I am interested in is a part of Excel Add-In).

In the Add-In I have:

- Public sapEEID As String
- Private Sub UpdateLetterTemplate

I am able to run the sub using the:
Application.Run ("'Solutions Add-In.xlam'!UpdateLetterTemplate")

HOWEVER, variable sapEEID = ""

Is there a way to pass "17" as sapEEID when running UpdateLetterTemplate private sub?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to modify your Subroutine somewhat but the following steps will work

- **Add Reference:** You need to add a reference to your add-in (VBE -> Tools -> References)
- **ByRef Parameters:** Also, make sure that your Sub can take a `ByRef` parameter. See sample code below.
- **Call the Subroutine:** You're done, now in your code, once the reference is set, call the sub and pass your variable.

**Sample Code for the Subroutine:**

```
Public Sub ChangeToTen(ByRef a as double)
    a = 10
End Sub
```

**Calling Code in your main file:**

```
Dim a as double
a = 1023.23

Call ChangeToTen(a)
MsgBox(a)          ' It will show 10
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you can make a reference to Excel add-in :)